# Find the limit joint distribution of the random vector uniformly distributed in the ball

Tags: uniform-distribution

Given an integer $n \geq 1$, define $\left(X_{1}^{(n)}, X_{2}^{(n)}, \ldots, X_{n}^{(n)}\right)$ as a random vector uniformly distributed in the ball
$$
 \left(X_{1}^{(n)}\right)^{2}+\left(X_{2}^{(n)}\right)^{2}+\cdots+\left(X_{n}^{(n)}\right)^{2} \leq n
 $$
Find the limit joint distribution of the random vector $\left(X_{1}^{(n)}, X_{2}^{(n)}, X_{3}^{(n)}\right)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is uniformly distributed in the ball $$B(n)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:||x||^2\leq n\}$$ then the pdf of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is $$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\frac{\Gamma\Big(\frac{n}{2}+1\Big)}{(\pi n)^{n/2}}$$ for $(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)\in B(n)$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: @MatthewPilling I think that the pdf must be $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\frac{\Gamma\Big(\frac{n}{2}+1\Big)}{(\pi)^{n/2}}$

Comment: @HuangDawei The volume of a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ withn radius $R$ (which in this case is $\sqrt{n}$) is $\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma\Big(\frac{n}{2}+1\Big)}R^n$

Comment: @MatthewPilling  But f(x_1,x_2,x_3) is needed rather than f(x_1,x_2,x_3,...x_n)

Comment: @KindergartenBoy2 your are right. I will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(X_1^{(n)},\ldots,X_n^{(n)})$ is uniformly distributed in $\Big\{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n:||\vec{x}||^2< n\Big\}$ then the pdf of $(X_1^{(n)},\ldots,X_n^{(n)})$ is the function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\frac{\Gamma\Big(\frac{n}{2}+1\Big)}{(n\pi)^{n/2}}$$ whenever $x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2 < n$ and $f(x_1,\dots, x_n)=0$ elsewhere. We find the joint pdf of $(X_1^{(n)},X_2^{(n)},X_3^{(n)})$ to be $$f_{X_1^{(n)}X_2^{(n)}X_3^{(n)}}(x,y,z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-3}}f(x,y,z,x_4,\dots, x_n)dx_4\ldots dx_n$$ If $x^2+y^2+z^2\geq n$ then $f_{X_1^{(n)}X_2^{(n)}X_3^{(n)}}(x,y,z)=0$ so assume $x^2+y^2+z^2 < n$ for the remainder of this post. We get $$f_{X_1^{(n)}X_2^{(n)}X_3^{(n)}}(x,y,z)=\frac{\Gamma\Big(\frac{n}{2}+1\Big)}{(n\pi)^{n/2}} \int_{\{x_4^2+\dots +x_n^2 < n-x^2-y^2-z^2\}}dx_4 \dots dx_n$$ Using the fact that a ball of radius $R$ in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ is $\frac{\pi^{k/2}}{\Gamma\Big(\frac{k}{2}+1\Big)}R^k$ we have $f_{X_1^{(n)}X_2^{(n)}X_3^{(n)}}(x,y,z)$ equals
the following expression $$\frac{\Gamma\Big(\frac{n}{2}+1\Big)}{\Gamma\Big(\frac{n-3}{2}+1\Big)}\Bigg(1-\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{n}\Bigg)^{n/2} \frac{1}{\Big(\pi(n-x^2-y^2-z^2)\Big)^{3/2}}$$ Using Stirling's approximation you will quickly see $$ f_{X_1^{(n)}X_2^{(n)}X_3^{(n)}}(x,y,z) \rightarrow \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ i.e. the limit joint distribution of $(X_1^{(n)},X_2^{(n)},X_3^{(n)})$ is $N\Big(\vec{0},I_{3\times 3}\Big)$.